# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in configuration process

Tags: port, config, opencart-3

This happened in my configuration process (3/4). I think this is because my database port is 3307 and not 3306. However, version 2.0.1 doesn't ask for port details. If this is the reason my configuration has paused, how do I change this?

Comment: please share code from database config file

Comment: The thing is there is no code in the config file during installation

Comment: Please check config.php file and look at username and password of database.